# Divide sequence elements into pairs

Tags: c#

I have a sequence of 16 elements: 1,2,3,..., 16 ( or 2*n elements). Sequence elements always goes from 1 to length(sequence) that is sequence of 4 elements is 1,2,3,4.

**Edit**: first sequence element is always = 1, second sequence element = 2, third sequence element = 3 and so on. **It's for a game "find a pair pictures"**.

I want to write an algorithm which divide elements into pairs. For Example,
1-15
2-16
3-13
4-9
5-14
6-10
7-11
8-12

PS: no linq please :) vs2005

**Edit**: As I can see, my question is so simple so no one can answer it :) Or everybody afraid something ?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Removed [algorithm]. Added [beginner].

Comment: Muad, no, it's not homework. Mitch, i ask a question because i have no code.

Comment: Also, it isn't entirely clear what you are looking for. You should clarify your problem statement.

Comment: "no linq please :)". any another not motivated limitations? what about "every answer should be typed with only right hand"? ;-)

Comment: Is there any significance to the way you paired the numbers in your example?  The choice of pairings seems odd given your length is 2n rather than 4n.

Comment: VeeArr, what exactly should I clarify ? I want to write a game "Pair pictures". I guess you know this game. I need an algorithm which divide that pictures into pairs.
zerkms, here, in russia, i work with vs2005 so i have no linq. tehMick, sequence length is always even.

Comment: @alex: then just specify your VS and/or .net versions so people can answer according them. ps: algorythm is still not clear enough to propose anything. pps: here in russia i use VS Express 2010 to work with modern technologies :-P

Comment: Do you want random pairs? I find no pattern in your example sequence...

Comment: zerkms, а что конкретно непонятно ? судя по ответам, вопрос настолько простой, что все боятся ответить. pps: где ? Peter, it's random pairs, but not random sequence elements. first sequence element always 1, second sequence element is always 2, third element = 3, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 8;

        List<int> tmpList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = size; i <= size * 2; i++)
        {
            tmpList.Add(i);
        }

        List<Pair> result = new List<Pair>();

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        {
            Pair pair = new Pair() { a = i, b = PopRandom(r, tmpList) };
            result.Add(pair);
        }

        foreach (Pair p in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.a, p.b);
        }
    }

    static private int PopRandom(Random r, List<int> list)
    {
        int i = r.Next(0, list.Count);
        int result = list[i];

        list.RemoveAt(i);

        return result;
    }

    struct Pair
    {
        public int a;
        public int b;
    }
}
```

**UPD**: this was compiled successfully for .net 2.0 target platform
**UPD 2**: Random instance moved out from PopRandom()

Comment: Pair pair = new Pair() { a = i, b = PopRandom(tmpList) }; Does that line also compile for .net 2.0 ? 

http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1714/tmpdl.png - pair 1-8 and 8-15 is wrong ...

Comment: upadted to be "more random" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without a selection criteria, just take every other one.....

```
var result = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();

for (int i = 1; i < size; i+=2 )
{
   var pair = new Tuple.Create(i,i+1);
   result.Add(pair);   
}
```